# Freemarker shortcut for boolean: "is not null and is true"

Tags: freemarker

This seems to show "Hello world" if foobar is defined

```
<#if foobar??>
    Hello world
</#if>
```

If foobar is a boolean, what do I use to write Hello world if foobar is both defined AND true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shortest I can think of is specifying a `false` default value:

```
<#if foobar!false>
    Hello world
</#if>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<#if foobar??>
<#if foobar?is_string>
    Hello world
</#if>
</#if>
```